# How to find the solution with string splitting?

Tags: php, string, laravel-5

I have an array of strings. Something like this

```
$preorder[] = "
         iPhone 7/7 plus\n
      \n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 AA/A - 1 550\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 HN/A - 50\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 - 1 500\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 LE/A - 1 550\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 AH/A - 1 600\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 VC/A - 1 550\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 MY/A - 1 550\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 2B/A - 1 550\n
      \n
       7 128Gb Black 1778 2B/A - 1 550\n
       7 128Gb Black 1778 VC/A - 1 550\n
      \n
       7 256Gb Black 1778 2B/A - 1 550\n
      \n
       7 128Gb Jet B 1778 VC/A - 1 550\n
      \n
       7 256Gb Black 1778 AH/A - 1 600\n
       7 256Gb Black 1778 AA/A - 1 550\n
       7 256Gb Black 1778 HN/A - 50\n
       7 256Gb Red 1778 MY/A - 1 550\n
      \n
       7 Plus 32Gb Black 1784 2B/A - 1 800\n
      \n
       7 256Gb Jet B 1778 MY/A - 4 950\n
       7 256Gb Jet Black 1778 - 1 500\n
       7 256Gb Jet B 1778 AH/A - 1 600\n
       7 256Gb Jet B 1778 HN/A - 50\n
      \n
       7 Plus 32Gb Silver 1784 2B/A - 5 200\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Black 1784 LE/A - 1 700\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Black 1784 HN/A - 50\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Black 1784 - 1 700\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Gold 1784 HN/A - 50\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Gold 1784 LE/A - 1 700\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Gold 1784 MY/A - 1 800\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Rose 1784 MY/A - 5 200\n
      \n
       7 Plus 128Gb Black 1784 2B/A - 5 200\n
        ";
```

This is a list of some products and I will send it to telegram. But telegram has limit on message length. So if my message have more than 4000 chars I need to split it to 2 messages.

But it's bad solution to split this string by empty line. So i have no idea how can I make this string looks like

```
$msg[] = "
         iPhone 7/7 plus\n
      \n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 AA/A - 1 550\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 HN/A - 50\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 - 1 500\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 LE/A - 1 550\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 AH/A - 1 600\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 VC/A - 1 550\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 MY/A - 1 550\n
       7 32Gb Jet B 1778 2B/A - 1 550\n
      \n
       7 128Gb Black 1778 2B/A - 1 550\n
       7 128Gb Black 1778 VC/A - 1 550\n";
       $msg[]="
      \n
       7 256Gb Black 1778 2B/A - 1 550\n
      \n
       7 128Gb Jet B 1778 VC/A - 1 550\n
      \n
       7 256Gb Black 1778 AH/A - 1 600\n
       7 256Gb Black 1778 AA/A - 1 550\n
       7 256Gb Black 1778 HN/A - 50\n
       7 256Gb Red 1778 MY/A - 1 550\n";
       $msg[] = "
      \n
       7 Plus 32Gb Black 1784 2B/A - 1 800\n
      \n
       7 256Gb Jet B 1778 MY/A - 4 950\n
       7 256Gb Jet Black 1778 - 1 500\n
       7 256Gb Jet B 1778 AH/A - 1 600\n
       7 256Gb Jet B 1778 HN/A - 50\n
      \n
       7 Plus 32Gb Silver 1784 2B/A - 5 200\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Black 1784 LE/A - 1 700\n";
       $msg[] = "
       7 Plus 32Gb Black 1784 HN/A - 50\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Black 1784 - 1 700\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Gold 1784 HN/A - 50\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Gold 1784 LE/A - 1 700\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Gold 1784 MY/A - 1 800\n
       7 Plus 32Gb Rose 1784 MY/A - 5 200\n
      \n
       7 Plus 128Gb Black 1784 2B/A - 5 200\n
        ";
```

So I want to split string by parts and make an array of them and then just send it to telegram. My string may have 20000 chars length. So I need dynamic way to split it.
Any suggestions? Thx!

Comment: So what have you tried?

Comment: try to use `preg_match_all()` for this purpose

Comment: @sietse85 preg_match_all to split a string? Don't you think there are other lighter functions to use?

Comment: `explode("\n", $preorder)` perhaps and then chunk the arrays or something like that, many ways to solve... he hasnt shown what he tried yet so...

Comment: I tried explode("\n", $preorder) but it will give me as much elements as lines I have in string

Comment: thats where `http://php.net/array_chunk` comes in

Comment: you could even make a char counter while iterating the array, so many options ;)

Comment: if you show me what you tried. i will write an answer for you

Comment: I solve my problem by writing next code https://pastebin.com/rhZcnS9w
array_chunk is the way I go. I also use implode to build new string with 100 lines or less. But maybe you can show me more elegant way?
Nevertheless it's looks like my problem is solved. Again thx for array_chunk

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

```
$lines = preg_split ('/$\R?^/m',  $preorder[1]);
        $arrays = array_chunk($lines,100);
        $new_line = [];
        foreach($arrays as $key => $value) {
            $new_line[] = implode("\r\n",$value);
        }
```

Thank you @sietse85 for array_chunk.

Comment: One extra notice: try to use `PHP_EOL` instead of `\r\n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop the exploded array of new line and count the number of characters in each line.
Sum it in a msgcount and keep adding to the string as long as you are below 4000 characters, once you go above 4000 split it and create a new array item.
Once all looping is done, you still have on message in the str, add that too and your done.
I added the count in the array also.

```
$msgcount = 0;
$str = "";
foreach(explode(PHP_EOL, $preorder[0]) as $item){
    $line = trim($item);
    $count = strlen($line);
    if($line == "") continue;

    if($msgcount + $count <= 4000){
        $str .= PHP_EOL . $line;
        $msgcount += $count+1;
    }else{
        $new[] = ["msg" => trim($str), "count" => $msgcount-1];
        $str = "";
        $msgcount = 0;
    }
}

$new[] = ["msg" => trim($str), "count" => $msgcount-1];


var_dump($new);
```

https://3v4l.org/JLPoU